# USA road restrictions in OSM from public state datasets

Tags: openstreetmap

I understand that most of the data in OSM for USA is coming from TIGER. It seems that this doesn't have complete road key attributes such as speed limit, maximum weight, allowed / restricted turns, lane change etc. I found that some state level DOT do have public datasets available for the roads within their jurisdiction, however some states don't have that.

I wonder if the OSM community knows if the data already available at these state DOT's was loaded in the OSM?

It is stated in the OSM webpage as well as in other GIS blogs that OSM doesn't have much data on key attributes of roads ie truck restrictions, however some DOT do have data on that. In OSM pages it wasn't clear if that data was loaded.

Comment: Since OpenStreetMap is open data I think any questions about its compilation should be asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why don't you ask the OSM community directly about this? https://community.openstreetmap.org

Comment: Already asked here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449545/usa-road-restrictions-in-osm-from-public-state-datasets